# How would I perform an sqlite backup through php

Tags: php, sqlite, codeception

I am attempting to use the sqlite backup command through php.

This requires 3 statements

- Opening the db `sqlite3 testing.sqlite`
- Backup the DB `.backup testing_backup.sqlite`
- Close sqlite `.exit`

The `exec` command doesn't like this as it hangs when the process stays open, I have tried running all three commands together using && to join them but this doesn't work either.

Can anyone help me run the 3 commands through php?

This is an attempt to create a backup file to solve a [database locking issue](http://technosophos.com/2011/05/26/sqlite-database-locked-error-and-unlocking-database.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sqlite3` command-line shall can also receive command(s) as parameters.

Just execute the following command:

```
sqlite3 testing.sqlite ".backup testing_backup.sqlite"
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.
I was hoping something like this was possible